Custom package security metadata (RPM)
I'm extremely new to packaging RPM's. I have an internal yum repository that I have RPM's for internal SSL certificates, but a few other programs/utilities that are simple enough to package that I can't find in RPM format.
I've created repos with the createrepo command, however I can't find much on how to provide package security metadata. The best article I've found so far is Setup Yum Repository with Security Metadata, which explains very nicely how to create the security metadata; however it is 6 years old (Not sure if anything here is out of date yet) and doesn't provide reference to the XML syntax/options (I don't find anything relevant whilst googling).
Was hoping someone could provide some references/guidance on how to properly configure/maintain a local repository with Security Metadata.
I'm hoping that including Security Metadata for my internal repos will compliment my patching and Errata auditing/reporting when leveraged with RedHat Satellite.
